# Python as Backend and Flutter as Frontend

Tags: python, flutter, frontend, backend

I am currently working on an app or rather preparing everything. However, I have a question regarding backend and frontend. For the frontend, I was thinking about working with Dart/Flutter, since I'm planning to release the app for iOS and Android. For the backend, I would actually like to use Python, since I also have experience with the programming language.

I want to build an artificial intelligence into my app, which can receive an input from the user via the frontend connection, do something with it and pass this processed information back to the frontend and thus to the user as output. I hope you can understand all this. So, in general, it just has to be able to pass the information between the Dart files (Flutter) and the Python files.

In fact, I don't really have any experience with linking a frontend with a backend. Now I just wanted to ask if all this is possible at all and if Flutter or Dart and Python are even "compatible" with each other, maybe with plugins or something? I don't want to do without Flutter for my app, so if that's not possible, which programming language could I use instead of Python for programming an artificial intelligence?

Maybe one of you already has experience in this area or with my problem and could help me? I am looking forward to your opinions and suggestions for help or also experiences.

Kind regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think the two are compatible, this coming from a developer who works in Django/Flask and Flutter (separately).

Comment: @Peter Are you saying Flutter cannot make HTTP requests? https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: I've never seen it done, and I've tried and failed. Just trying to warn you

Comment: Well, documentation clearly shows its possible. Backend programming language doesn't matter. The serialization/communication layer does

Answer (score 3):

I'm a Fullstack developer and I have worked on a bunch of these projects with Front-end and Back-end components.

Essentially what you would do is have your Front-end make get requests to a server. Your Front-end client would be in Flutter or Dart and the server would be an HTTP API. Flask, for example, is one framework that let's you make web applications with Python. You are making an API for your client to call.

I can't speak as much to Flutter or Dart because I'm a React.js developer, but you would host your client on one website and then host a server on another website and simply make get and post requests on the server.

Comment: Note: question was asking about mobile clients, not websites/JS

Comment: Its the same concept, the only difference is that you have a mobile application for your Front-end Client instead of a website.